# How to get key from key value object in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I need to get key from the key value object inside array.

```
$scope.rolehiddenfields = [{"aboutyou": "aboutyou", "height": "height"}];
```

But want as `$scope.allrolehiddenfields = ["aboutyou", "height"];`

Comment: [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)!

Comment: Thanks I got it. How can i reform the above object from newly updated "$scope.array = ["aboutyou", "height"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
Object.keys({ "aboutyou": "aboutyou", "height": "height" })
```

Comment: Thanks I got it. I have one more doubt that how can i remove last index value ","

Comment: Thanks I got it. How can i reform the above object from newly updated "$scope.array = ["aboutyou", "height"];

Answer (score 4):

```
Object.keys($scope.rolehiddenfields[0]);
```

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks I got it. How can i reform the above object from newly updated "$scope.array = ["aboutyou", "height"];